# Making a popup appear over a hyperlink in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I currently am using a simple javascript code to get a popup of data to appear when you click a hyperlink of a table.

However, I am unable to have the popup appear near the link whatsoever. Does anyone have any suggestions or better versions of scripts that can perform this action? jQuery is an option as well.
 Thanks, here is my current javascript code:

```
function createPopup(x, y, divID) {
    var p = document.getElementById(divID);
    p.style.display="block";
    p.style.Left = x;
    p.style.Top = y;
    document.body.appendChild(divID);
}
```

And this is the css

```
.popup {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: thin solid #000000;
    color: black;
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

This is the link I use to popup the div.

```
<a id=buttonRed href="javascript:createPopup(\'-40px\', \'' . (-15 + ($resultCounter * 10)) . 'px\', \'Name' . $id . '\');">
```

As you can see the data is dynamic as I am pulling the data dynamically.

The popup works well other than the fact that the popup does not appear near the hyperlink.

Suggestions?

UPDATED CODE::

```
    <script>
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
        if (window.Event) {
            document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
        }
        document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
    }

    function getCursorXY(e) {
        document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
        document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
    }

    function createPopup(divID) {
        var p = document.getElementById(divID);
        p.style.display="block";
        p.style.Left = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);;
        p.style.Top = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);;
        document.body.appendChild(divID);
    }
</script>
```

This is what I have for the javascript but it is still not loading at the correct location.

Comment: Rather than passing static x/y values to the function, you should do it based on the current position of the cursor - as it can be reasonably assumed that the cursor will be near the link when the link is clicked. [A quick Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+cursor+position) will tell you how to do this...

Comment: That is a great suggestion Dave, Let me try it out. Will it give me results in pixels?

Comment: It will give you the results as a integer in pixels, where the top left corner of the viewport is 0/0. [This page](http://dev-notes.com/code.php?q=33) will I think get you rolling in the right direction.

Comment: It is not working properly. I will post the javascript I wrote in my post. Let me know where I am going wrong. I am still relatively new to javascript so bear with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use JQuery instead then you can just grab the offset of the clicked link and add it to the css of the popup. Something like this:

```
$("#buttonRed").click(function (e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var topOffset = 35;
    $(".popup").css('left',offset.left);    
    $(".popup").css('top',offset.top - topOffset);
    $(".popup").css('display','block');
});
```

The `topOffset` variable determines how much higher it should be with regards to the clicked link. You can also add a leftOffset variable as well obviously. I have set up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mn6rg/

Comment: I have different divs that load for each hyperlink. Unfortunately, the way the website is setup.. all these hyperlinks have to use the id=buttonRed. Is there any other identified I can use to distinguish which hyperlinks open which div if I use this method?

Comment: Just add an a to the selector tag like so: `$("a#buttonRed").click(function (e) {`. Now it will add the click event to all links with that id. Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/mn6rg/1/

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I misread your comment. If you need separate popups for the links you could give a different class to each link and then use that class as a selector: `$(".link1").click(function() {`. There's probably a better way but just thinking off the top of my head.

Comment: Well all these divs are going to use the same popup class. They will all have to look similar. However link1 will have to open div1 link2 will have to open div2. The only issue is unfortunately ALL the links have to have the id=buttonRed due to a parent script that runs on this page.

Comment: What if I create a javascript function to load jquery commands. Is that possible?

Comment: The class will go on the link not the popup. You can also have several classes in one element. `<a id="buttonRed" class="red link1">red link with a second class</a>`. Now you can select the link1 class with jquery but also retain the red class.